# Import a JavaScript file in HTML file inside of try-catch block

Tags: javascript, html, try-catch

I have a HTML page into which I want to import a JS file as follow:

```
<script src="file.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

But in case this file fails to run its scripts, the whole page obviously gets stuck.

Can I import that file inside of a try-catch block?

Comment: Fixed your formatting - you might want to check that what I fixed it to is what you're actually doing.

Comment: Where is it imported? In the head? Try moving it in front of the closing body tag.

Answer (score 5):

You can listen for an error (see [**this**](http://pieisgood.org/test/script-link-events/))

```
// make a script
var s = document.createElement('script');
// set it up
s.setAttribute('src',"file.js");
s.setAttribute('type',"text/javascript");
s.setAttribute('charset',"utf-8");
s.addEventListener('error', errorfunction, false);
// add to DOM
document.head.appendChild(s);
```

then in `errorfunction`, find out what happened & try to fix it as you would in a `catch`

Comment: Thanks...but the thing is, that the html page first imports the above file, then runs scripts on the html regardless. Now, some times the page runs without any internet connection outside of the local network, and the file im trying to call is on a remote server, and I get an error that prevents from the other scripts on the page from running....

Comment: If you're expecting not having file access, cache it or save it locally

Comment: tried it...saved the file locally...but it's a problem bc inside it, it uses calls for other files that have relative paths on its server...downloading them all can be a long game...

Comment: If you want to read something you don't have, you have to get ahold of it first.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). This assumes you have [jQuery](http://jquery.com), but you can easily avoid using it ([here](http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/) you can find one of many tutorials). Here's an example:

```
$.get("http://yoursite.com/file.js", function(data) {
    try {
       eval(data); //Run the JavaScript, which is equivalent to adding it
    }
    catch (err) {
       //handle errors
    }
});
```

Hope that helped in any manner!

Comment: hey 
Thanks for your help...but what about the utf8 charset?
How do I configure the get call to use it?

Comment: and I tried that but I got 
"XMLHttpRequest cannot load http:"myfile".js. Origin http://192.168.1.224 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

Comment: @user1432779 That's because you can't do AJAX communication with another server.

Comment: Yeah...I've read about it just now..any other option for try catch on a remote js file import?

Comment: @user1432779 Well, you could disable error-reporting all-in-all, would that be sufficient?

Comment: That doesnt sound reasonable..isn't it on done through windows?
Isn't there anyway to call that file like the usual html import mechanism does?

Comment: This is also *very* insecure, incase the file gets hacked!

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like that or create JS element and set src inside this element

```
document.write("<script src=\"file.js\" type=\"text/javascript\" charset=\"utf-8\"></script>");
```